# Syncfusion sfChart merges categories

Tags: syncfusion-chart

I have a stacked chart that can have categories with series with negative values. Whenever there are negative values the chart control merges the categories. I don't want this behavior, anyone know what might be causing it?

Aug 2023 is supposed to be shown separetely in the chart below. As far as I can tell all the series X and Y configuration is correct because it works fine when there are no negative values.

[image: Chart with merged rows]

I also use Syncfusion charts in an ASP.NET Core project and there they behave as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to stop this behavior by setting `IsIndexed` to `False` on the `CategoryAxis`.